# How can I program obstacles in a snake game? (Python 3 and Turtle graphics)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, game-development

I'm trying to program a snake game with Turtle in Python 3 and so far everything has gone well, but now I have a problem. 
And my problem is that the snake just moves through the obstacles, although I want the game to restart as soon as the snake head hits one of the obstacles.

And by the way, it is my first program so I hope that the answer to my question is not too obvious.

---

Snake head

```py
head = turtle.Turtle()
head.speed(0)
head.shape("square")
head.color("red")
head.penup()
head.goto(0, 0)
```

Obstacles

```py
ob1 = turtle.Turtle()
ob1.speed(0)
ob1.shape("square")
ob1.color("black")
ob1.penup()
ob1.goto(0, 100)
ob1.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=20)

ob2 = turtle.Turtle()
ob2.speed(0)
ob2.shape("square")
ob2.color("black")
ob2.penup()
ob2.goto(0, -100)
ob2.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=20)
```

---

First I tried that:

```py
if head.distance(ob1) < 20 or head.distance(ob2) < 20:
    restart()
```

But the problem with this is, that only one part of the obstacle will restart the game as soon as the snake touches that part but the rest of the obstacle poses no danger because the snake can easily move through this rest of the obstacle.

And that's because the obstacles, despite their size, only occupy one field of the window, namely the field that I determined with `ob1.goto (0, 100)`.

---

And then I tried to make lists filled with the coordinates of the obstacles and then use these lists to compare the numbers they contain with the Y and X position of the snake's head:

```py
numbers = []

y = range(-200, 200)
for n in y:
    numbers.append(n)

if head.ycor() == (numbers):
    restart()
```

But still the snake could move through all of the obstacles.

Comment: The second way will work, but you want `head.ycor() in numbers` insteand of `head.ycor() == (numbers)`. That checks to see if the ycor is in the list, rather than whether ycor _is_ the range object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine now :D